# Firebase cloud scheduler function cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

Firebase indicates the cost for cloud scheduler jobs as $0.10 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Does that mean you would be charged $864 dollars per month if you had a job that ran every 5 minutes???

Updated: Even though answered, just to clarify the reason I asked the question is because the docs referenced did not distinguish between a "job" and as Doug mentioned, the invocation. If you are going to down-vote, it would be helpful to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about product pricing. Please use the established costumer support channels for sales of the product.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, the cost is per job definition, not per job invocation.  If you define 3 jobs, it's $0.30 per month, no matter how many times they execute.

Comment: Thanks Doug, that's what I wanted but didn't see anything in the documentation explicitly addressing invocation or execution. Much appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that you are also still paying Cloud Functions cost per invocation on top of the scheduler cost.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: @LovetoCode the first 3 jobs are free: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing

Comment: @DougStevenson `Each Google billing account gets 3 jobs per month free. Note that the free tier is measured at the account level not the project level. For example, if your account has 5 projects with 2 jobs each, you will have 3 free jobs and 7 paid jobs.` so if i only have 3 jobs then its free!?

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for clarifying the bill of cloud functions